# React: Problems importing reducer function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to user pass a Redux store to my components using context, with the Provider provided by `react-redux`. I am doing this way:

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import eventsReducer from './GlobalReducer';  // <= IMPORTING

import './index.css';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStore(eventsReducer)}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Route component={GlobalHeader} />
                <Route component={GlobalFooter} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

My reducer function is declared this way:

#### GlobalReducer.js

```
import EventActions from './actions/EventActions';

class GlobalReducer {

    eventsReducer = function(state = {},action) {
        switch(action.type) {
            case "LOAD_INITIAL_STATE":
                return {...state, events: EventActions.load()};
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

};

module.exports = GlobalReducer.eventsReducer;
```

It happens that I get an error:

> > ./src/index.js
> >
> > 23:22-35 "export 'default' (imported as 'eventsReducer') was not found in './GlobalReducer'

I even tried the arrow syntax here, but it didn't help.

I tried writing it in many ways:

1) Using

```
import GlobalReducer from './GlobalReducer';
```

and then writing

```
<Provider store={createStore(GlobalReducer.eventsReducer)}>
```

and then the error changes to

> > Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.

2) Exporting the function with

```
module.exports = GlobalReducer.eventReducer;
```

importing it like

```
import eventsReducer from './GlobalReducer';
```

and then using it as

```
<Provider store={createStore(eventsReducer)}>
```

and then the error changes to

> > ./src/index.js
> >
> > 23:22-35 "export 'default' (imported as 'GlobalReducer') was not found in './GlobalReducer'

I even tried to take the function out of the class and export it directly using `module.exports`. It didn't work too!

What exactly am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line `module.exports = GlobalReducer.eventsReducer;` by `export default GlobalReducer.eventsReducer;`

Then, import it with: `import eventsReducer from './GlobalReducer';`.

You won't use `GlobalReducer.eventsReducer` anymore, but just `eventsReducer`.

Comment: 1) When I used `export default` and `{ eventsReducer}`, as in your first suggestion, I got another error: `'./GlobalReducer' does not contain an export named 'eventsReducer'`

Comment: 2) This second suggestion is exactly what I am doing above. See the first case I mention, please.

Comment: You have `module.exports`. Change it by `export default GlobalReducer.eventsReducer`

Comment: I used `export default GlobalReducer.eventsReducer;` and then `import eventsReducer from './GlobalReducer'`, but then I get `Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.`

Comment: I used export default GlobalReducer.eventsReducer; and then `import { eventsReducer } from './GlobalReducer', but then I get `'./GlobalReducer' does not contain an export named 'eventsReducer'.`

Comment: You don't need curly braces. You are already exporting the function with `export default GlobalReducer.eventsReducer`. Use just `import eventsReducer from './GlobalReducer'`

Comment: It worked with `export default function eventsReducer(state = {},action)` and then `import eventsReducer from './GlobalReducer';`.

Comment: Great, that's the approach I use, instead of creating a class.

Comment: My idea in creating a class was gathering all possible reducers inside it and then having a reducer method built with combineReducers(). It would help having everything in a single place.

Comment: Of course, you can do it without a class. In the same file, just have a bunch of functions (or import several files) and export the `combineReducers` of all of them in the `reducers/index.js` file. Then, you import the "global reducer" with `import reducer from './reducers'`

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

This is usually how I structure my projects. Note the changes in folder structure. Perhaps this will work for you as well.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import reducers from './reducers';  // <= IMPORTING

import './index.css';

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Route component={GlobalHeader} />
                <Route component={GlobalFooter} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

**./reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import events from './events';

export default combineReducers({
    events
});
```

**./reducers/events.js**

```
import EventActions from '../actions/EventActions';

export default (state = {}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "LOAD_INITIAL_STATE":
            return {...state, events: EventActions.load()};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```